# Can I read a range of rows using pandas data frame on some column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my data,

```
prakash  101
Ram      107
akash    103
sakshi   115
vidushi  110
aman     106
lakshay  99
```

I want to select all rows from **akash** to **vidushi** or all rows from **Ram** to **aman**. In real scenarios, there will be thousand of rows and multiple columns and I will be getting multiple queries to select a range of rows on the basis of some column value. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Heres the right way to do it..

```
start = 'akash'
end = 'vidushi'

l = list(df['names']) #ordered list of names
subl = l[l.index(start):l.index(end)+1] #list of names between the start and end

df[df['names'].isin(subl)] #filter dataset for list of names
```

```
2   akash   103
3   sakshi  115
4   vidushi 110
```

Answer (score 0):

Create some variables (which you can adjust), then use `.loc` and `.index[0]` (note: `df[0]` can be replaced with the name of your header, so if your header is called `Names`, then change all instances of `df[0]` to `df['Names']`:

```
var1 = 'Ram'
var2 = 'aman'
a = df.loc[df[0]==var1].index[0]
b = df.loc[df[0]==var2].index[0]
c = df.iloc[a:b+1,:]
c
```

output:

```
    0       1
1   Ram     107
2   akash   103
3   sakshi  115
4   vidushi 110
5   aman    106
```

Answer (score 0):

try `set_index` then use `loc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["prakash","Ram","akash","sakshi","vidushi","aman","lakshay"],"val":[101,107,103,115,110,106,99]})
(df.set_index(['name']).loc["akash":"vidushi"]).reset_index()
```

output:

```
      name  val
0    akash  103
1   sakshi  115
2  vidushi  110
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the range to select rows

```
print x[2:4]

#output
akash    103
sakshi   115
vidushi  110
aman     106
```

If you want to fill the values based on a specific column you can use `np.where`