# How to select a range of row of data from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

for eg.

```
     name
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d 
.    .
.    .
.    .
59   .
```

I want to select data from range 25 to 40.

Comment: Use `df.loc[25:40]`

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I read a range of rows using pandas data frame on some column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845440/can-i-read-a-range-of-rows-using-pandas-data-frame-on-some-column-value)

Comment: FYI: I just wrote this, because it has been answered in the comments here and is probably a duplicate.